# Is "has has" form correct?

Tags: tenses

Example sentence:

> Skype *has has* since confirmed that a solution is in the works.

Shouldn't it be:

> Skype *has had* since confirmed that a solution is in the works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as if the repetition of *has* was unintentional. Your suggested amendment is equally ungrammatical, I'm afraid.